# Help in proving continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am doing question 4.6.2. in Understading Analysis. The question goes as follows:

Given a countable set $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, .... \}$, define $f(a_n) = 1/n$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\not\in A$ Find $D_f$. Where $D_f$ is the set of points where the function $f$ fails to be continuous.

Proving that every point of A is not continuous is not a problem. My problem is showing that that  $x \in A^c$ is either continuous or not. I think my intuition is saying that they should be.

Could anyone point me in some direction on how to prove this?

Comment: What about when $A$ is the set of positive rational numbers?

Comment: Think about the worst case of one point, how near can the nearest element of $\{a_n\}$ be?

Comment: @vonbrand could you check my suggested proof?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion to a proof:

We have the set $A = \{a_1, a_2, ...\}$ and the function $f(a_n) = 1/n$ and $f(x) = 0$  $\forall x \not\in A$. We are going to find $D_f$. We know that A is countable, that tells us that A does not contain any form of intervals from \mathbb{R}. We thus know that $A \subseteq D_f$. Pick any $a_n \in A$ sett $\epsilon < \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ you  will never be able to find a $\delta$ s.t. $|x-c| < \delta$ then it follows that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$. We must also check whether also the set/subsets of $\mathbb{R}/A$ also belongs $D_f$. Lets check if $x \in \mathbb{R} /A$ is continuous. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Go in each direction of $x$ and search for the first $a_{n_0}$ s.t. $1/n_0 \leq \epsilon$. Set $\delta < |a_{n_0}-x|$. By constructing $\delta$ this way we have found a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ for $y \in V_{\delta}(x)$, and we conclude that $D_f = A$.